# How do I make jQuery input string clippings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wat to change some e-mail input to get only the text before `@` using jQuery.

For example:

Code:

```
$("#email").keyup(function () {
 var gecici = $(this).val();
    if (gecici.indexOf("@") != -1) {
        // not an e-mail, skip
        return false;
    } else {
        //CODE...
    }
});
```

Input / Output example:

```
email: test@domail.com >> test
```

Comment: Not clear on your question - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: remove tag, improve description

Answer (score 1):

Can't really do much string manipulation using jQuery as far as I know, but normal javascript can handle it.

I interpret it like your looking for something like `gecici.split('@')[0];` to get the name/prefix before the `@` character.

Example:

```js
$("#email").keyup(function () {
    var gecici = $(this).val();
    if (gecici.indexOf("@") != -1) {
        $('#name').text(gecici.split('@')[0]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Email: <input id="email" type="text"/> Name/prefix: <span id="name"></span>
```

Using keyup might not be the best bet for this. Firstly, it requires more processing than is required. Secondly, it will not work with auto-complete or copy & paste (using mouse anyway). It would be better to check this when field loses focus, or when form is submitted.

Comment: @FotoşokluAdam You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as **answer** if this was the solution you were looking for.